# linking pages in ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a beginner in `Ionic`, I am getting an error when clicking on the links. Below is my `index.html` page and I want the list items to linked to other pages.

> Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
    <title>my test App</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
        @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }  @viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }
        @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }           @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionic.css">
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header">
        <button class="button icon ion-navicon button-assertive"></button>
        <h1 class="title">Header</h1>
        <button class="button icon ion-home button-assertive"></button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader bar-dark">
      <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content class="has-subheader">
        <ul class="list">
            <a href="/pages/item1.html"><li class="item">Item 1</li></a>
            <a href="/pages/item2.html"><li class="item">Item 2</li></a>
        </ul>
    </ion-content>



    <div class="bar bar-footer bar-energized">
        <h1 class="title">Footer</h1>
    </div>


    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
        app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my root folder where `index.html` is present I have a directory named `pages` and under this directory I have two html pages `item1.html` and `item2.html` which I want to be linked with list items `Item 1` and `Item 2` respectively. 
But whenever I click on the first list item (Item 1) I get an message i.e **Cannot GET /pages/item1.html**, anyone please suggest me how can link pages.
thank you

Comment: You forgot to close `<script>` tag just above `</body>`. Do you get `Cannot GET /pages/item1.html` ?

Comment: yes now after I added a slash ( / ) before the link I get the exact line you wrote i,e `Cannot GET /pages/item1.html`

Comment: Did you close <script> tag just above </body> and try then?

Comment: For me your code works after I closed `<script>` tag and without a slash ( / ) before the link `href="pages/item1.html"`.

Comment: sorry but now it is going to a 404 page
**404 : Intel XDK can't find your app. Do you have index.html in your source directory**

Comment: I think there must be something wrong in the `item1.html`...please see below script, it is my item1.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            Hello world
        </body>
    </html>

Comment: Create new Ionic project [link](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) `$ ionic start myApp blank`, copy your code to _index.html_, put _ionic.css_ in folder **www/css** and then copy folder **pages** with _item1.html_ and _item2.html_ in **www** folder and this should work. For me your code works from the first time after I closed `<script>` tag. This may mean that you have some other problems and 404 means that something is not in a place where it should be.

Comment: ok let me try...actually I created this project by using Intel XDK, because if I create the project by cmd then I cannot able to run it, the emulator opens but it doen not display the project

Comment: hi, I run it using the command `ionic serve` , but same problem, `Cannot GET /pages/item1.html`